# python thrift dependency works in python2 but not in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, thrift

I have the following dependecies in requirements.txt.

```
confluent-kafka==1.0.1
enum34==1.1.9
kafka-python==1.3.2
more-itertools==5.0.0
psutil
pyhashxx==0.1.3
requests
simplejson
thrift==0.11.0
watchdog==0.9.0
zipp==1.0.0
future
```

This works fine in python2 but I get the following error in python3.

```
 Running setup.py bdist_wheel for thrift ... error
  Complete output from command /home/sshil/code/metrics-agent/ma3_venv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-z7tikgl_/thrift/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpteb8buiypip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for thrift
  Running setup.py clean for thrift
Failed to build thrift
Installing collected packages: confluent-kafka, enum34, kafka-python, six, more-itertools, psutil, pyhashxx, chardet, idna, urllib3, certifi, requests, simplejson, thrift, PyYAML, argh, pathtools, watchdog, zipp, future
  Running setup.py install for thrift ... done
Successfully installed PyYAML-5.3.1 argh-0.26.2 certifi-2020.4.5.2 chardet-3.0.4 confluent-kafka-1.0.1 enum34-1.1.9 future-0.18.2 idna-2.9 kafka-python-1.3.2 more-itertools-5.0.0 pathtools-0.1.2 psutil-5.7.0 pyhashxx-0.1.3 requests-2.23.0 simplejson-3.17.0 six-1.15.0 thrift-0.11.0 urllib3-1.25.9 watchdog-0.9.0 zipp-1.0.0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+error%3A+invalid+command+bdist_wheel